# Assigning a different set of layers to each project stored in a QGIS GeoPackage

Tags: qgis, layers, geopackage, qgs

I have a QGIS GeoPackage storing several vector layers and three projects.

The QGIS User Guide, chapter 6. Working with Project Files, states: ‘The information saved in a project file includes ‘Layers added’.

The User Guide chapter is really talking about saving a project which are saved to QGS/QGZ files.

My question is: in a QGIS GeoPackage, which contains multiple projects, could each project include its ‘Layers added’, too? If that is so, how do I achieve this?

My problem is that each of the three projects within my GeoPackage includes identical set of layers chosen from the packaged layers in that GeoPackage: removing a layer from one project, also removes that layer from the other two projects in the GeoPackage; adding a layer to one of the projects, the same layer is automatically added to the other two projects in the GeoPackage.

Is there a way to make a different selection of layers for each project within a single GeoPackage?

Comment: I think you're confusing things a bit. a GeoPackage contains data, like tables of points and polygons. A project stores your connections to those data.

Comment: Have a look at menu Project - Save To - GeoPackage. It is possible to save also the project into GeoPackage.

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the answer is yes: you can store inside one and the same Geopackage file different layers + projects. Projects can have loaded different layers, but you should add them inside the project. Geopackage is a container format, imagine it like a folder or a zipped file, containing multiple files and folders.

However, functionality depends on QGIS version and there might be bugs. Saving projects to Geopackage was [introduced in QGIS 3.8](https://www.qgis.org/de/site/forusers/visualchangelog38/index.html#feature-qgis-projects-inside-geopackage-files). So even if in principle it should work, the very reason why it does not as expected depends on the very context: your QGIS version, Operating System, the file and data you use etc.

And: even though you can store everything in the same Geopackage, for practical reasons it still might not be the best idea - this is good for sharing whole projects + data, but for productive use and to keep an overview, I would still keep data and projects as separate files.

Comment: Could you, please, elaborate on your suggestion that I ‘should add them [layers] inside the project’. – This is precisely my query: how? – As I understand it, to add layers to a project
(i) set the project: Project menu > Save To > GeoPackage … > selecting the relevant GeoPackage project from the Project drop down list;
(ii) add the project’s layers: Layer menu > Data Source Manager > GeoPackage tab > selecting the relevant layers and clicking the Add button; the selected layers show up in the Layers panel and the map canvas.

I run QGIS 3.20.0 on a desktop computer with Windows 10.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct. However, to see in detail what works and what not, inspecting you Geopackage would be good.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help; I am not sure how to go about sharing my GeoPackage for your to ‘inspect it’. - I will put together a package with just one or two layers from the QGIS online tutorials and see if I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, you should upload it to a cloud and share the link here.

Comment: Yes, packaging just 5 shapefiles from the QGIS exercise data to a GeoPackage and then adding two projects to the GeoPackage exhibits exactly the issue I described: the result of adding/removing a layer from one project is automatically reproduced/mimicked in the other GeoPackage project.

- The projects in the GeoPackage, I am developing, share many of the GeoPackage layers. I hoped, that each of the projects would have their own set of layers, too, to deal with a particular aspect I wish to explore. I thought, it would be simpler to switch between the projects within only one ‘container’.